# How to extract columns of data from .txt files MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have some data in a .txt file. that are separated by commas.

for example:

```
1.4,2,3,4,5
2,3,4.2,5,6
24,5,2,33.4,62
```

what if you want the average of columns, like first column (1.4,2 and 24)? or second column(2,3 and 5)?

I think putting the column in an array and using the built in mean function would work, but so far, I am only able to extract rows, not columns

---

instead of making another thread, I thought i'd edit this one. I am working on getting the average of each column of the well known iris data set. 
I cut a small portion of the data:

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa

delimiterln= ',';
data = importdata('iris.txt', delimiterln);


meanCol1 = mean(data(:,1))
meanCol2 = mean(data(:,2))
meanCol3 = mean(data(:,3))
meanCol4 = mean(data(:,4))
```

Undefined function 'sum' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in mean (line 115)
        y = sum(x, dim, flag)/size(x,dim);

Error in irisData(line 6)
meanCol1 = mean(data(:,1))

it looks like there is an error with handling data type...any thoughts on this? I tried getting rid of the last column, which are strings. and it seems to work without error. So i am thinking that it's because of the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use comma separated file reading function:

```
M = csvread(filename);
```

Now you have the matrix M:

```
col1Mean=mean(M(:,1));
```

Comment: With Matlab it pays to get into the "vectorization" mindset as early and often as possible:  `mean(M, 1)` gets you the mean of all columns at once.

Comment: is the csvread only for numbers? what if there is an additional column of strings? is there a way to exclude only that column?

Comment: okay, I think I know how to do the range of rows, so it would be like

Comment: actually I found: M = csvread(filename,R1,C1) and M = csvread(filename,R1,C1,[R1 C1 R2 C2]) for range bounded calculations